# Indicator which disappear when we have reached last item in a HorizontalScrollView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, mobile, horizontalscrollview

I have a subclass of HorizontalScrollView in which I am adding multiple images.
I have to show some kind of indicator at left and right end of screen which shows if there are items remaining on left and right side. Also the respective indicator should disappear when we have reached relevant end.

Can someone tell me the options available for this?

```
     protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {

             View view = (View) takeparent().getChildAt(takeparent().getChildCount()-1);  //this is the last view
             int diff = (view.getRight()-(getRight()+getScrollX()));// Calculate the scrolldiff
             if( diff == 0 ){  // if diff is zero, then the rightmost end has been reached
                 right.setVisibility(View.GONE); //setting the right button invisible
             }


             View viewleft = (View) takeparent().getChildAt(0);  taking the first View 
             int diffleft2 = (viewleft.getLeft()-(getLeft()+getScrollX()));// Calculate the scrolldiff

             if( diffleft2 == 0 ){  // if diff is zero, then the bottom has been reached
                 left.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 }



             super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer to your now modified question:

```
@Override
public boolean canScrollHorizontally(int direction)
{
    final int offset = computeHorizontalScrollOffset();
    final int range = computeHorizontalScrollRange() - computeHorizontalScrollExtent();
    if(range == 0){
        return false;
    }
    return (direction < 0) ? (offset > 0) : (offset < range - 1);
}

protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt)
{
    left .setVisibility(canScrollHorizontally(-1) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    right.setVisibility(canScrollHorizontally( 1) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}
```

I would recommend Drawables over using Views'.

So, I've extended `HorizontalScrollView` and overridden the `draw()` method to draw its own `Drawable`'s to the `canvas` for the indicators. The rest of it is simply managing the position of them using `setBounds`, and now a pressed state.

Code: https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/4c017f776663bf6dd5d8#file-indicatedhorizontalscrollview-java

Comment: Can you please explain your answer. I didn't get you.

Comment: Sorry but I still didn't get you as it says nothing about how to show and disappear indicator on reaching respective ends. The indicator lets assume is a button

Comment: IF you want the indicators to be clickable. Then there is a better approach. Which is it? Do you want clickable indicators? or not.

Comment: Please see if you can help me in this question. I am trying to resolve this problem for 2 days. Please see. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23835529/making-modified-range-seek-bar-in-android#23835529